# Widget for accepting email addresses

Tags: looking-for-a-script, widgets

I have a non WordPress website in which I'd like users to submit their email addresses. Is there a website widget that I can use to plug this in quickly?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to collect the email addresses you can create forms using services like [JotForm](http://www.jotform.com/) or [WuFoo](http://wufoo.com/) and embed the forms into any website. The forms can include multiple fields of any type (including email address). Both services collect the data for you and you can get to it by logging to your account there or you can receive an email with the responses. Both have free starter editions.

On the other hand, if you are collecting email addresses so you can send out a mass email to those people who sign up, then services like MailChimp or iContact are more what you are looking for. They not only collect the email address, but also allow you to design/write an email and then do all of the mass sending for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save that yourself, then you will need a small script which will save things on user input in your database. If you want you can use 3rd party service like feedburner or mailchimp (but these will require the user to click a link in an email to verify their subscription.